How to get the value of a specific column? I'm executing a SQL query in linq using C#
I am trying to get the value of my column authID so I can authenticate the user authority in my login form. Please help me I'm new to Linq. Thank you.
This is my code
acpEntities db = new acpEntities();

public void authenticateUser()
{
    var sqlQuery = db.user_tbl.SqlQuery("OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY
encryptUserPass DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pa$$w0rd'; SELECT userID, username, pass = CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(pass) AS nvarchar), authID, RID, isActive, timestamp, transDate FROM user_tbl WHERE username = @username AND CAST(DECRYPTBYKEY(pass) AS nvarchar) = @pass", 
                                        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@username", txtUsername.Text), 
                                        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@pass", txtPassword.Text))
                                      .ToList();

    if (sqlQuery.Any())
    {
        frMain main = new frMain();
        main.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid account, please contact your administrator", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    authenticateUser();
}

The code is working, I just don't know how to get values to a specific column using this sqlQuery to execute a query in Linq using C#. I've been searching on Google and Youtube by I can't find any answers

What is db?..

I forgot to add it. It's acpEntities db = new acpEntities(); entity data model

You don't decrypt a stored password (it should be near impossible to decrypt a stored password; they should be one way hashed) and compare it with the readable password your user sent in. Instead you hash the password your user sent in and compare it with the stored hash. If the hashes match, the password was right. Putting your password decryption key into the software isn't much better than just storing the passwords plaintext

I got it. string authority = sqlQuery.FirstOrDefault().authID;
